# Get Syntax Error: Expected end of input but got keyword ORDER at [5:1]: in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run the following I get the error Syntax Error: Expected end of input but got keyword ORDER at [5:1]:

SELECT
purchase_price
FROM
`test-project-349410.customer_data.customer_purchase` LIMIT 1000
ORDER BY
purchase_price DESC;

I have tried a semicolon after the project name, semicolon after DESC. This from the Google Data Analytics course and it was typed exactly as they presented in the video.  Not sure how to make this run.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the LIMIT clause and the ORDER clause.

```
SELECT
  purchase_price
FROM 
  test-project-349410.customer_data.customer_purchase
ORDER BY purchase_price DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

Deeper cut:  If it's of interest to you, there's more details on SQL syntax in BigQuery at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax